# Why the Russell class $\mathcal{R}(p)$ is not a set?

Tags: analysis, set-theory

I've been studying Von Neumann-Barnays-Gödel axiomatic set theory (NBG) from Dugundji's Topology (1966) presented in chapter 8, and the statement 8.3 in the books still doesn't make sense to me, or at least the logical thinking it takes to get there: "the Russell class $\mathcal{R}(p)$ is not a set".

This is affirmed because of Axiom I of Individuality: a class is uniquely determined by its defining property, so with this terminology, we can deduce the stated. More explicitly, the books says:

> Because of Axiom I, the class $\mathcal{A}$ is uniquely determined by its defining property; we will denote $\mathcal{A}$ by the notation $\{x | (x \text{ is a set}) \wedge p(x)\}$ and sometimes by $\mathcal{A}(p)$- Observe that with this terminology, the Russell antinomy becomes the harmless statement: **8.3** the Russell class $\mathcal{R}(p)$ is not a set.

Also, the Axioms and definitions stated before this property are the following:

- **Axiom I (of Individuality)** $\left(x \in A\right) \wedge \left(x = y\right) \implies y \in A$
- **8.2 Definition** The class $A$ is called a set if there is a class $\mathcal{A}$ such that $A \in \mathcal{A}$
- **Axiom II (of Class Formation)** For each property $p$ in which only set variables are quantified and in which the class variable $\mathcal{A}$ does not appear, there is a class $\mathcal{A}$ whose members are just those *set* having property $p$; in symbols: $\left( x \in \mathcal{A} \right) \iff \left( x \,\,\text{is a set} \right) \wedge p(x)$.

So I'm not sure if I am understanding it correctly: we can deduce that the Russell class is not a set, because from Axiom of Individuality, a class is purely determined by its elements, and so its elements should be a set, but from the Axiom of Class Formation, the logical predicate $p(x) = x \notin x$ should be able to form a set but instead leads to a contradiction $\mathcal{R} \in \mathcal{R} \iff \mathcal{R} \notin \mathcal{R}$?

I believe my reasoning is failing in some point. I would be very thankful of other explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about how to apply Axiom II: let's take $p \equiv \lnot x \in x$. So the axiom is telling you that there is a class $A$ such that  ${\cal x} \in A \Leftrightarrow (\mbox{$x$ is a set}) \land \lnot x \in x$. This $A$ would be our candidate Russell class $\cal R$. The axiom instantiated with $x \equiv \cal R$ gives you that ${\cal R} \in {\cal R} \Leftrightarrow (\mbox{$\cal R$ is a set}) \land \lnot {\cal R} \in {\cal R}$. But, unlike what happens with an unrestricted axiom of class formation, this is harmless: it just implies that $\cal R$ is not a set: if it were, we would have the contradiction that ${\cal R} \in {\cal R} \Leftrightarrow \lnot {\cal R} \in {\cal R}$, but the axiom implies that $\cal R$ is not a set and we have no contradiction.